# Optimization of PHP function

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony function that need a lot of optimization. This function compares a question with all it's answers to calculate a mark for each answer. Problem is each question has around 1000 answer. Each exam has up to 60 questions.
All question fields and reponse fields are boolean.
Question and reponses are objects.
How can I do to make this faster and consumes less memory ?

```
public function correctionReponseTest($question)
{
    $reponses = $question->getReponses();
    if ($question->getMultipleChoices())
        $bareme = $this->_em->getRepository(Bareme::class)
            ->findOneBy(['nom' => 'QCM']);
    else
        $bareme = $this->_em->getRepository(Bareme::class)
            ->findOneBy(['nom' => 'QCS']);

    $item1V = $question->getItem1Vrai();
    $item2V = $question->getItem2Vrai();
    $item3V = $question->getItem3Vrai();
    $item4V = $question->getItem4Vrai();
    $item5V = $question->getItem5Vrai();
    $item1A = $question->getItem1Annule();
    $item2A = $question->getItem2Annule();
    $item3A = $question->getItem3Annule();
    $item4A = $question->getItem4Annule();
    $item5A = $question->getItem5Annule();


    foreach ($reponses as $reponse) {
        $repA = $reponse->getA();
        $repB = $reponse->getB();
        $repC = $reponse->getC();
        $repD = $reponse->getD();
        $repE = $reponse->getE();
        $repAv = $reponse->getAv();
        $repBv = $reponse->getBv();
        $repCv = $reponse->getCv();
        $repDv = $reponse->getDv();
        $repEv = $reponse->getEv();
        $repV = $reponse->getV();
        if (!$reponse || ($repA == null && $repAv == null && $repB == null &&
                $repBv == null && $repC == null && $repCv == null &&
                $repD == null && $repDv == null && $repE == null &&
                $repEv == null && $repV == null)
        ) {
            $nbBonnesReponses = 0;
        } 
        else {
            if ($repV) {
                $nbBonnesReponses =
                    (($item1V == $repAv) || ($item1A))
                    + (($item2V == $repBv) || ($item2A))
                    + (($item3V == $repCv) || ($item3A))
                    + (($item4V == $repDv) || ($item4A))
                    + (($item5V == $repEv) || ($item5A));
            } 
            else {
                $nbBonnesReponses =
                    (($item1V == $repA) || ($item1A))
                    + (($item2V == $repB) || ($item2A))
                    + (($item3V == $repC) || ($item3A))
                    + (($item4V == $repD) || ($item4A))
                    + (($item5V == $repE) || ($item5A));
            }
        }
        $reponse->setNote($bareme->getScore($nbBonnesReponses));
        $this->_em->flush();
    }
}
```

QC table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `qc` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ordre` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`titre` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`enonce` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`item1` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`item2` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`item3` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`item4` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`item5` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`corrige_item1` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`corrige_item2` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`corrige_item3` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`corrige_item4` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`corrige_item5` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`item1_vrai` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`item2_vrai` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`item3_vrai` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`item4_vrai` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`item5_vrai` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`multiple_choices` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`inclu` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`donnees` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
`item1_Annule` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`item2_Annule` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`item3_Annule` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`item4_Annule` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`item5_Annule` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`qcPere` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_colle` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`id_tuteur` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`coefficient` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '1.00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: just thoughts. I would expect to see arrays used more. i.e. `$questionItem[$itemIdx] = $question->getItemVrai($itemIdx);`. However, I would need to see the database table structure, some sample table data and expected output. I suspect that the information that should be stored as rows is being stored as columns. I suspect that the code can have a lot of the hard-coded variable names removed and still be easy to understand.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I already thought of creating an Item entity. I even tried once but I have 2 problems with that :
- I want my Question entity to have only 5 Items Entity for now and I don't know how to set the limit, create each Question with its 5 Items easily and to set a specific order for these Items.
- I'm afraid of the performance hurt of multiplying entities especially when all the calculation is already taking a lot of time.
I updated my question with table structure.

Comment: I would suggest that you always try the simplest 'natural relation' with SQL and this is `row` for repeated items not columns. imo, you don't have anywhere near enough data to cause performance issues on a desktop pc.

Comment: Ok then I'll try that. I also think it's a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Calling flush will commit changes to db. Since you do not retrieve any new information from db while doing the loop **(?)**, you dont have to run flush() until after the loop.

So move flush() outside of the loop.

Comment: I moved flush outside the loop and it's already working better. Thanks a lot